# Powershell doesn't find file

Tags: powershell

This is my powershell script:

```
cd '\\ac.gf\root\M151 Agie Charmilles SA\Qualità\QP\6-SPC - tools\2-Tools\IPC\Mechanics\OFFICE_2016'
$file = 'SPC_Analysis_v2.3 - 36 mesi_250_macchine.xlsm'
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
```

I need to open the file in the specified path, it exist but powershell doesn't find it.
Powershell reported that couldn't find it. [image]
Listing the content of the folder I can see that it exist

Comment: Most likely, "Current directory" for your powershell doesn't get inherited by the process that runs Excel. You will probably have to specify the full path to the file, and you might not need the `cd` statement at all, so I would instead just move the entire path into the `$file` variable, and I assume it would then work.

Comment: Thank you, solve, add it as a reply to the post

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1.) Set the `CurrentDirectory` (this is not the same thing as the "location" in powershell)

```
 [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
 # or
 [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($pwd)
```

2.) Use the full path

```
 $x1.workbooks.Open((Get-Item $file).FullName)
 # or
 $x1.workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path $file))
```